# Distribute a network with sub networks properly

Tags: networking

Currently i have only 1 subnet 192.168.1.0/24 with the following

- Group1: Servers 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
- Group2: Printers, Scanners 192.168.1.2-192.168.39
- Gateway, DHCP 192.168.1.1
- Group3: Laptops, Desktops, etc. 192.168.1.40-192.168.1.239

but I running out of IPs

I want to switch to four subnet but have a question. If Group3 must access to all servers, servers must have an IP in each subnet? or as it is the best way to do this?

I wont something like this:

- Group1: All devices First floor   192.168.2.*
- Group2: All devices Second floor  192.168.4.*
- Group3: All devices Thrid floor   192.168.6.*
- Group4: etc devices               192.168.8.*

some guidance to help me with this issue

Comment: Why aren't you just enlarging the subnet? What are the business or technical reasons for creating separate subnets?

Comment: Creating VLANs based on floors of a buidling is a wrongheaded reason for creating VLANs. You create VLANs to segment varying security concerns, and to limit flooding of broadcast and frames with unknown destinations.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup 4 subnets and want to access the other subnets, your gateway must route the traffic.

Layer 3 switches will typically do this for you, but a standard linux box will do it if you enable ip forwarding.

Say your gateway has the interfaces:

```
eth0: 192.168.2.1/24
eth1: 192.168.4.1/24
eth2: 192.168.6.1/24
eth3: 192.168.8.1/24
```

By enabling IP forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You will be able to access IP's from a different subnet through your gateway. Please remember to configure your firewall (pf/netfilter) accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know, currently my gateway is linux box

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

`1.` You divide the networks, and you configure your single gateway in each of those networks. The only issue you might have in this situation is NETBIOS style network browsing. proper DNS can resolve that quite easily.

`2.` You make your subnet larger, instead of a `/24`, you make it a `/23` and get another 256 addresses for free..

Comment: That is one reason why each group has a subnet of separation. thanks for the tip